# How to parse multiple XML files from a folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am making a html site for displaying XML data for easy printing.

The XML data is delivered from a form and is stored in a share.

The names of the XML files are dynamic

> replay"the date".xml

I have made the website that parses a specific XML file and adds some css style.
But I need to be able to parse all the files.

this can be done by having the user select the specific XML file or some other solution.

I have used HTML, JavaScript

the solution could be JQuery, php or something else

XML example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<formreply name="form9" replyid="20131023092257_ua36el69kc4c8r2klrq6b46s40" sessionid="ua36el69kc4c8r2klrq6b46s40" tswhen="1382512977" date="2013-10-23 09:22:57"
<data>
  <element id="bra" heading="" optid="FREE-TEXT">bra</element>
  <element id="id" heading="" optid="FREE-TEXT">bra</element>
 </data>
</formreply>
```

Comment: The files could be uploaded to the server or the user could select the file to be parsed on the client side. But the user has to be able to choose the specific XML they want to view in html.